# How to Use FirebaseFirestore with Paging 3 Library?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata, android-paging-3

I wanted to build an application like Twitter where I have to display a list of data sets with live updates for counting like and comments in real time.

For that, I am using

1. RecyclerView - for displaying list of scrollable data
2. Jetpack LiveData - for observing changes and notifying observers.
3. Firestore - As a backend for getting realtime data with snapshot changes.
4. Paging 3 - for loading large set of data into list by chuncks.

But how would I implement the firestore query with PaggingSource class by emitting live changes to the list?

```
class FirebasePagingSource() : PagingSource<QuerySnapshot,ItemModel>() {

override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<QuerySnapshot, ItemModel>): QuerySnapshot? {
 // Need guidance for implementation
}

override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<QuerySnapshot>): LoadResult<QuerySnapshot, ItemModel> {
 //Need guidance for implementation
} }
```

**Here ItemModel is a data class**

**2. ItemListLiveData Class**

```
class FirestoreQueryLiveData(private val query: Query)
: LiveData<List<Item>>(), EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {

private lateinit var registration: ListenerRegistration

override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()
    registration = query.addSnapshotListener(this)
}

override fun onInactive() {
    super.onInactive()
    registration.remove()
}

override fun onEvent(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
    snapshot?.let {
        val documents= mutableListOf<Item>()
        for (document in snapshot.documents) {
            document.toObject(Item::class.java)?.let {
                documents.add(it)
            }
        }
        postValue(documents)
    }
} }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Maybe this article, [How to paginate Firestore using Paging 3 on Android?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df) together with this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestorePagination) will help.

Comment: And if you want to use Jetpack Compose, here is another [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of useful guides online. In general, you can set a stream of paged data from Firestore into a Recycler View and from there it is simply a matter of paginating each request.

This can be a lengthy and involved process, so I will link a recommended tutorial, its source, and the relevant youtube guide.

- Medium: [https://medium.com/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df)
- Github: https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestorePagination/
- Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JOzozH5eOQ

Comment: .await () is not working-> unresoulable reference

Comment: `.await()` is not a thing - you should evaluate your code and ensure it is equivalent with any tutorial you are following

Comment: For .await() to work, you must first enable Courotine for firebase. Just add these 3 dependencies


    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1"